# In hibernate what is the correct way to insert or update a record?

Tags: hibernate

A colleague implemented a "insert or update" function for an entity using the following code that runs in a transaction.  It is supposed to update an existing record or create it if it does not exist.

```
    EntityManager em = ...;

    public void saveMyEntity (MyEntity entity) {
        em.persist(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    }
```

This looks wrong to me for so many reasons:

- is is doing what merge already does, checking for the entity presence
- If em contains the entity there is no need to persist it
- If is also useless to call persist after merging the entity
- it doesn't check whether an entity with the same ID exists in the DB
- and it should return the merged entity if it did merge it

I believe the following code works just as well, but I am not yet very familiar with hibernate and I might miss something.

```
    public MyEntity saveMyEntity (MyEntity entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
```

Can anyone confirm my analysis?

I should clafify that the use of the `saveMyEntity` function is to save to the DB an entity that was either retrieved using hibernate (with `em.createNativeQuery`) and updated, or created with `new MyEntity()` if the entity was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Using `merge` is correct. Eventually performance will get better as we implement merge with the native database "upsert" syntax, similar to what we did for https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16727